# What could a year long journey look like, while traveling near the speed of light, through the lens of that telescope?

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light, time-dilation, space, telescopes

Hypothetically speaking if you had a satellite going near the speed of light in a straight line towards an exoplanet light years away and that satellite had a telescope pointed at the surface of an exoplanet.

**What could a year long journey look like, while traveling near the speed of light, through the lens of that telescope that what light years away pointed directly at the surface of the exoplanet?**

would the telescope capture the planet in fast forward as the light information would be entering the telescope faster? Would it be slower as time dilates for exoplanet because it not moving the sleed of light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant effect is the [relativistic Doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect) for light.

The signal from the exoplanet is blue-shifted by a factor of
$$ \frac{f_{\rm obs}}{f_{\rm emitted}} = \sqrt{\frac{c+v}{c-v}}\ , $$
where $v$ is the relative speed of satellite and exoplanet.

This formula combines the regular Doppler effect and the time-dilation factor of Special Relativity. i.e. It can be written as
$$ \frac{f_{\rm obs}}{f_{\rm emitted}} = \left(1 + \frac{v}{c}\right)\left(1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{-1/2}\ . $$

So yes, if you could observe details of what was happening on the exoplanet, they would appear to be speeded up by this factor.